# Convert varchar to date SQL to order SQL query

Tags: sql

In my DB I have rows like this:

```
id   name   date_start   date_end
1    Test   10-04-2021   10-04-2021
2    Test2  12-04-2021   12-04-2021
3    Test3  05-04-2021   05-04-2021
```

The `date_start` and `date_end` are `VARCHAR`.

I want to SELECT only the rows with upcoming date (equal to today or future).

I found something like this:

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 105)
```

So I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` convert(`date_start`, getdate(), 105)
```

But this returns an error. Can someone explain how to fix this?

Comment: You fix this by using `date` as column type

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Please correct your tags.

Comment: Don't store dates as strings. That's the real error. The real fix is to convert these fields to `date`. Anything else is just trying to cover up the critical bug, and can easily lead to bad data. You *can't be certain* what `05-04-2021` means. Is that May 4 or April 5? Are you sure the buggy application that used strings instead of dates didn't use US-style ordering? If someone used the wrong type, someone could also forget to set the web site's locale

Comment: No matter the database (that CONVERT is T-SQL) , using strings instead of `date` is simply wrong. **Nothing** prevents the storage of mixed format date literals. Once that happens, there's no way to recover the original date. Yes, *some* dates may only be parsed with a specific format, but what happens with those that could be parsed either way?

Comment: To highlight Pana's comment above, what is the format of your date strings?  Without knowing at least that, you won't get anywhere with this question.

Comment: Missing `WHERE`, between the FROM clause and the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the date to store in database in YYYY-MM-DD Format and use date as type then you can simply create a query like.

**`select * from` table_name `where start_date>=(_date_in_YYYY_MM_DD_format)`**

or in another way is that you can store timestamps rather than date.

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid syntax for several reasons:

- After a table name, what is expected is a table alias.  Your expression is not a valid table alias.
- Presumably you want a filtering clause, but there is no where.
- If you are using SQL Server, the first argument to `convert` is a data type.
- If you are using SQL Server, then backticks are not appropriate.

In SQL Server, you would implement the logic you want as:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table_name t 
WHERE convert(date, date_start, 105) >= convert(date, getdate())
```

The syntax would be quite different in MySQL (which the backticks suggest might also be the database you are using).  In either database, you should focus on fixing the data, so the dates are stored using the correct type (hint:  `date`) not as strings.